# How do I got notified while my cache replication finished?

Tags: caching, ignite

I have a scenario that I will start a ignite cache node(node1) with cache mode(CacheMode.REPLICATED) first. And the other cache node(node2) with the same cache name will be started in the future for synchronizing data from node1. I have a question of "How do I got notified when the cache synchronization from node1 to node2 is finished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronous rebalancing for this: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rebalancing#rebalance-modes

If rebalance mode is `SYNC`, new node will not complete start process until data is fully replicated.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder if having any way to get notified when my cache synchronization finished?

Comment: You don't need notification in this case. `Ignition.start` will finish and public API will become available only after rebalancing is done.